# array list with model class store multiple values at same index

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, saxparser

I am working with sax `xml parsing` and storing data to `array list` with model class.

On the basis of that i am generating `buttons` dynamically.

Here is the `xml` data.

```
        <SalesLocation>

            <SalesLocationGroup>0</SalesLocationGroup>

        </SalesLocation>
        <SalesLocation>

            <SalesLocationGroup>0</SalesLocationGroup>

        </SalesLocation>
        <SalesLocation>

            <SalesLocationGroup>1</SalesLocationGroup>

        </SalesLocation>
        <SalesLocation>

            <SalesLocationGroup>2</SalesLocationGroup>


        </SalesLocation>
        <SalesLocation>

            <SalesLocationGroup>3</SalesLocationGroup>

        </SalesLocation>
        <SalesLocation>

            <SalesLocationGroup>4</SalesLocationGroup>

        </SalesLocation>
```

Now here with above xml on the basis of `Sales Location Group Value` i am adding buttons to `Linear Layout`.

```
private ArrayList<ModelSalesLocation> arrayListSalesLocation;

final Button tableButton = new Button(this);
    tableButton.setId(iTable);
    tableButton.setText(arrayListSalesLocation.get(iTable).getSalesLocationName());


final LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    if (arrayListSalesLocation.get(iTable).getSalesLocationGroup().equals("0")) {
        int wd = ((Integer.parseInt(arrayListSalesLocation.get(iTable).getTableWidth()) * deviceWidth) / 1080);
        Log.w("Final Width", "" + wd);
        linearParams.width = wd;

        int ht = ((Integer.parseInt(arrayListSalesLocation.get(iTable).getTableHeight()) * deviceHeight) / 1776);
        Log.w("Final Height", "" + ht);
        linearParams.height = ht;

        int top = ((Integer.parseInt(arrayListSalesLocation.get(iTable).getTopLocation()) * deviceHeight) / 1776);
        Log.w("Final Top", "" + top);
        linearParams.topMargin = top;

        int left = ((Integer.parseInt(arrayListSalesLocation.get(iTable).getLeftLocation()) * deviceWidth) / 1080);
        Log.w("Final Left", "" + left);
        linearParams.leftMargin = left;

        linearTableMain.addView(tableButton, linearParams);
}
```

**Now here if `Sales Location Group` contains 0 multiple times and so on others then i need to add it to array list on same index.**

Currently i am getting both values on different index.

How to add that multiple values at same index and show buttons on basis of that.

Let me know if you need more information in this regards.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

have a hash map like `HashMap<integer,List<String>>`
eg 
`sampleList.add(index1data);sampleList.add(index2data);`

`sampleMap.put(0,sampleList)`

Comment: I know with `HashMap` but what we can do with current scenario using `ArrayList` of model class ?